# Why won't MSpec integrate with ReSharper 6?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, mspec, resharper-6.0

I'm having trouble with getting MSpec to work with ReSharper 6. I've just installed MSpec from the NuGet package:
[image: Installed MSpec from NuGet]

Next, I've quit from Visual Studio, opened an elevated command prompt and run the install script from the packages\tools folder:
[image]

And finally, reloaded Visual Studio. No dice! No icons in the text editor and no plugin shows up in the ReSharper options.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? The MSpec site says this is supposed to work :(

Comment: If you get this issue, in my accepted answer below there is a manual installation method. I've found that to be more reliable then using the batch file. Close Visual Studio, delete all the MSpec stuff from the ReSharper plugins folder then manually copy the files over as described below.

Comment: I have this problem now. Any further updates on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hand copied:

`Machine.Specifications.dll` and `Machine.Specifications.ReSharperRunner.6.0.dll`

to the `"%APPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.0\vs10.0\Plugins"` folder

as per the instructions, but the integration didn't appear until I had restarted VS2010 and re-loaded the solution.

[MSpec for Resharper 6](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/07/machinespecifications-for-resharper-6-now-available/)

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure I tried restarting everything, but will try the manual process and see if it helps.

Comment: @Tim - You are using 6.0 and not the 6.1 EAP?

Comment: Ok it's started working now. I closed everything, deleted all the existing MSpec stuff from teh ReSharper plugins folder, then manually copied the files over, and hey presto! Working test runner. I've had problems like this before and it seems like the installer batch file might sometimes fail silently and leave the wrong files installed or something. In future I'm going to stick with doing it manually I think.

Comment: Please let me know if you can think of ways how the batch "installer" can be improved!

Answer (score 1):

Windows blocks DLL's that have been downloaded from the internet. Unblock the Machine Specification DLL's from a folder that does not require admin rights and put them back into the Resharper plugins folder. Restart your Visual Studio and reload your project, ReSharper should pick up your MSpec tests.

Useful Link: [Help configuring MSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782457/help-configuring-mspec)